# Increase width value successively by specific value jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have this very simple progress bar which I want to "move" with each run of my function.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td width=2000 style="padding:none">
    <hr class="progbar" style="background-color:#c00;height:20px; border:none; margin:0;" align="center" width=2% /></td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

If I simply do this:

```
$(".progbar").css("width", "30%");
```

is pushes the bar to 30% width once. What I want is that it increases successively with each run of my function (basic keypress function).

I tried this to set a variable "l" and increase it with each run and then rewrite the above to:

```
$(".progbar").css("width", "l");
```

But this does not work.

How can I increase the width of my basic progress bar with each run successively by the amount of, say, 10%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `$(".progbar").css("width", "l");` to the following:

```
$(".progbar").css("width", l);
```

Your variable should not be included between quotes.

See the jsfiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/fJZ32/